# How to remove JSON object/Token from JSON with changing keys

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How can I delete objects having removethisobject="yes"  in path rootkey3.variablekey1.properties, rootkey3.variablekey2.properties. The challenge is that rootkey3 can have keys with different name and are not fixed which means that  variablekey1, variablekey2 etc. can be anything.)

changingjson

```
{
 "rootkey1": "rv1",
 "rootkey2": "rv2",
 "rootkey3": {
   "variablekey1": {
     "childkey1": "ckv1",
     "Properties": {
       "Description": "g desc",
       "id": "ck1id",
       "fewdetails": 
       [
         {
           "removethisobject": "yes",
           "name": "name1",
           "age": 21
         },
         {
           "removethisobject": "no",
           "name": "name2",
           "age": 22
         }
       ],
       "moredetails": [
         {
           "removethisobject": "yes",
           "name": "namefmd1",
           "age": 21
         },
         {
           "removethisobject": "no",
           "name": "namefnd2",
           "age": 21
         }
       ]
     }
   },
   "variablekey2": {
     "childkey1": "ckv2",
     "Properties": {
       "Description": "g desc",
       "id": "ck2id",
       "fewdetails": [
         {
           "removethisobject": "yes",
           "name": "name1",
           "age": 21
         },
         {
           "removethisobject": "no",
           "name": "name2",
           "age": 22
         }
       ],
       "moredetails": [
         {
           "removethisobject": "yes",
           "name": "namefmd1",
           "age": 21
         },
         {
           "removethisobject": "no",
           "name": "namefnd2",
           "age": 21
         }
       ]
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Tried following code in C# and get an exception

```
 var myJobj = JObject.Parse(changingJSON);
 var rk3 = myJobj.SelectToken("rootkey3");
            
 foreach (var ck in rk3)
 {
     var ck1 = (string)ck["childkey1"]; // exception 
 }
```

I am using latest version of Newtonsoft and .Net fx 4.7

Comment: foreach (var ck in rk3.GetChildren()) { ... }, try this.

Comment: can't see GetChildren method for rk3

Comment: sorry it is rk3.Children()

Comment: tried with rk3.Children(), still getting exception on same line

Comment: what are you trying to do just to get the value of the childkey1? And what is about remove json object?

Comment: We hare to remove the objects having "removethisobject"="yes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if it can help you,

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var myJobj = JObject.Parse(json);
var rk3 = myJobj.SelectToken("rootkey3");

foreach (var ck in rk3.Children())
{
     var ck1 = ck.SelectToken("$..childkey1").ToString();
}
```

Comment: How can i fetch variablekey1 or variablekey2 as strings

Comment: `var vk1 = ck.SelectToken("$..variablekey1").ToString();`

Comment: can't use variablekey1 as part of the path as these are generated dynamically